# Converting 12-hour time to 24-hour time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, convert, time

I have a data set with hours such as 8am to 6pm.
I would like to convert this from 12 hour clock format into 24 hour clock format.
So instead of "8am to 6pm" I would want "08:00-18:00"

How can I do this in QGIS, using Field Calculator, or using a script with Python?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom function in the Field Calculator that will do this for you. I created a function `converter()` which worked to convert the text "8am to 6pm" into the text "08:00-18:00":

```
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def converter(value1, feature, parent):
    return datetime.strptime(value1.split(" to ")[0],'%I%p').strftime('%H:%M') + "-" + datetime.strptime(value1.split(" to ")[1],'%I%p').strftime('%H:%M')
```

For some reason in QGIS 2.18 it would only take a single-line function, so I have had to stick it all in one line. What it does is split on the *" to "* portion of the text input, then formats *"8am"* and *"6pm"* into 24 hour time using the `strptime`/`strftime`.

After saving this in the run this in the *"Function Editor"* within a new file, navigate back to the *"Expression"* tab and run: `converter("YourFieldName")`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to export the attribute table to excel, then to search and replace with Excel (or an other software) and finally to join the table.
There is maybe a simpler solution, but if you have to change just a data set, you won't lose lots of time.